# What are your techniques for discovering unwanted global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

Since global variables in javascript are anything but best practice, I'd like to discover any unintentional global variables in javascript...just noticed one in a method I'm currently working on. So my question is...

What techniques, other than a careful reading of code, do you use to discover unwanted global variables?

Are there any tools available for this purpose?

Found this page, [Remy Sharp's bookmarklet for detecting global vars,](http://remysharp.com/2007/11/01/detect-global-variables/) on a quick google search, but I'm wondering if there are others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer on SO.

Comment: I ran jslint, and it didn't catch it...are there some configuration settings in jslint for discovering unintentional global vars

Comment: @w4ik could you edit your question to include an example of a global var that JSLint did not catch? I have never had this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help folks...user error... jslint says Undefined variable: postlookupTableCodeId

Comment: image does not seem big enough